# What tools are available for managed file transfer?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-compression, file-merging

I'm looking for some good examples of `Managed File Transfer` tools.

This is in an enterprise / corporate setting, where we wish to automate some recurring file transfer tasks. Our bunch of cobbled together scripts just doesn't cut it anymore.

I'm looking for the following capabilities:

- Has a decent scheduler.
- Is "job-oriented" (you define jobs by adding parts to it).
- Where you can import and export jobs as simple text (xml, source, ..) files so they can be managed in source control.
- Has options to send and retrieve files using multiple protocols (smb, ftp, http, onedrive, etc..).
- Can perform some basic file operations (zip / unzip, merge / split, encrypt / decrypt, encode, ..).
- Can alert operators when things go wrong (job was not started, input was not ready, error during processing, etc..).

What would you recommend? Please provide some experiences as well when 
possible...

I'm looking for software that can run in a Windows (domain) environment, and we will mostly be working xml, csv, flat file, pdf or zip files.

Comment: I have the same question, we are currently checking out: http://limagito.com/